# Make a picturebox change itself very fast between 2 pictures (Windows Forms app)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to make a picture change itself very fast between 2 pictures. I have the pictures saved in the debug folder of the program.

Here is the image of pictures with there names saved:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ9g5.png

So here is the code were I save a picture in the picturebox so that there is not an empty picturebox

```
private void Gamble_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     pictureBox1.Image = (Image.FromFile("21.png"));
}
```

And here is the timer click method I think I need to use for this action

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image is null;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which part did you get stuck on?

Comment: I tried to do a timer stuff I googled it but I can't understand how it works I'm pretty new to programming this kind of stuff I was only used to do arrays and alghoritmic stuff sry if my question is stupid

Comment: Use one of the images as the BackgroundImage of a PictureBox, use a Field to hold a reference to the second Image (to load when the Form loads). In the Timer's `Ticks` handler, write `[Some PictureBox].Image = [Some PictureBox].Image is null ? [The other image] : null;`, where `[The other image]` is the Field that stores your second image. -- Don't set the Timer's `Interval` to less than 35ms (the *official* min. interval is 55ms).

Comment: So do I need to create a class wich has a picture property or just save the other picture in another variable ?

Comment: And also the Black images is saved with the "21" name and the Red one with "20" name

Comment: If you want to swap images a few times a second a timer is fine. Have you considered multiple picture boxes, swapping their visibility? If you want to swap images every frame without any tearing, that's a whole other kind of question.

Comment: I just want them to change a few times a second

Comment: Already described: use a Field to store an Image, e.g., `Image timerImage = null;`. When the Form loads, load the image, e.g., `timerImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([The Image path])));`. In the `Tick` handler, add the line show before. Replace `[Some PictureBox]` with the name of your PictureBox and `[The other image]` with `timerImage`. -- You can set the `BackgrounImage` of your PictureBox at design-time or when you load the other image. Set the Interval of the Timer to whatever you want but above 35ms.

Comment: can't I just use this timer.Image = Image.FromFile(name of the image ) insead of this timerImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([Image Path])

Comment: A Timer doesn't have an `Image` Property. Why don't you simply test that code and see how it goes?

Comment: I understand everythink until the part with the tick handler  again sry for my stupidy but i don't understand this part [Some PictureBox].Image = [Some PictureBox].Image is null ? [The other image] : null;, where [The other image]

Comment: I know some PictureBox = PictureBox1 and the other image is timerImage but I don't understand why PictureBox1.Image = PictureBox1.Image is null I don't understand this

Comment: The code in the Tick handler is `pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image is null ? timerImage : null;` -- This means: If the Image Property of `pictureBox1` is null, set  `timerImage`, otherwise set `null`. So it alternates no image with the `timerImage`. When there's no image, you see the `BackgroundImage` of your PictureBox.

Comment: so it gives me this error cannot implicity convert type bool to "System drawing Image" also i edited the timer_tick with the code so you can see it

Comment: You didn't write what I've posted. That's a conditional operator (or ternary conditional operator). See the guide about it: [?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) -- If you have `nullable` enabled, you have to declare the Field as `Image? timerImage = null;`

Comment: I did Image timerImage = null right before Gamble Load

Comment: Read again my comments, from the first one. Try to write exactly what I wrote. If you change something without knowing the consequence, it won't work. -- As in `pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image is null;` that's not what I wrote at all. -- Last comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this in your Gamble_Load:

```
var t = new Timer(x => pictureBox1.Image = (Image.FromFile("otherimage.png")), null, 1000);
```

This creates a timer that will fire after 1 second and update the image.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0

Comment: This would really do nothing, except leaking an Image per second (if it could work). BTW, you're referring to a  Threaded Timer: even if that code could work, you cannot update Controls from a Thread other than the UI Thread.